# Find integers that satisfy $a^2b -2N = -c^2$

Tags: divisibility, diophantine-equations, integers

Find integers that satisfy $a^2b -2N = -c^2$ where $a,b,c,N$ are positive integers, and $N$ is a big integer that I am trying to factor.

One direction that I had is to multiply $N$ by a small integer $k$ because then I can say:

$$\left(\frac{n+k}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{n-k}{2}\right)^2=Nk$$

It's pretty close to $a^2b +c^2 = 2N$, but then I don't see how it can help. Also $k$ must be an odd number, while I really want it to be 2.

Solving it will help me with my factorization idea [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814276/idea-for-running-the-quadratic-sieve-in-a-sub-quadratic-space-like-the-general-f).

Here is an example of such numbers.

- $N = 3161= 29 * 109$
- $a = 9$
- $b = 78$
- $c = 2$

Comment: Is there a typo in your first equation?  It doesn't exactly match an equation from the Question you reference and since it is $a^2 b + b^2 = 2N$, you are apparently directly searching for a factor of $2N$, so (excepting the easy factor $2$) seems to beg the question.  The closest match from the referenced Question would be $a^2 - 2N = -b^2$ or $ab - 2N = -c^2$.

Comment: @EricTowers tnx, I fixed it

Comment: Found them, not restricdted to idoneal numbers, any $mx^2 + n y^2$   will do, and they even work out allowing $n$ negative. John Brillhart, 2009, A Note on Euler's Factoring Problem......Richard Blecksmith, John Brillhart, and Michael Decaro, 2016, Using Conic Sections to Factor Integers. Both in the Monthly of the MAA

Comment: 2009:   http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Brillhart_Euler_factoring_2009.pdf

Comment: 2013, a (simplified version appeared in2016): https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1375361973

Comment: You might see a pattern by trying out easy to find values of $a$ where
$$a\in\{2,3,8,9,14,15,20,21,26,27,32,33,34,35,40,41,46,47,54,55,58,59,64,65, ...\}$$

Comment: What's wrong with $a=c=1$ and $b=2N-1$?